# PHP or Javascript:Check if cookie is set, if it is change content of a <li>

Tags: php, javascript, html, cookies, set

I am developing a website in which a cookie is set when the user logs in.
Before the user logs in, a < li > shows the test "Client Login". This is fine, but what I want is to change the content when they are logged in by checking that the cookie is set.

IE:

**NOT Logged in:**

`<li><a href="#">Client Login</a></li>`

**Logged in:**

`<li><a href="#">Client Tools</a></li>`

I thought that this could be done by PHP or javascript or anything?

Can anyone help please?

(Fairly new to this.)

Thanks very much!

Comment: Yes, it can be done with PHP and/or Javascript. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I hope your client area has more protection than a cookie `loggedIn = yes`.

Comment: MrCode: It has more than that, that is one of the cookies. There is actually 4. :)

Comment: What are in the other 3 cookies that protect the client area from unauthorised access?

Comment: @deceze: Yes. THe webpage wouldn't load.

Comment: @Mr Code They are "PPSESSIED" which has some random string in it., "user_id", which has a couple of numbers in it, "user_key" whuch has another lengthly string in it, and "user_name" which is self explanatory.

Comment: I think hes getting at: If your not storing the actual login status server side then anyone could set/change the cookie to bypass your login security.

Comment: @harley for me there is a large question mark over your login security. Regarding the question though, you should do the link switch on the server side. There is no logical reason or benefit to doing it with Javascript. If you have a session variable to store the logged in status then use that instead of a cookie. Additional cookies to say `loggedin = yes` are redundant and could become mismatched with the session ID cookie if you have a session based login system.

Comment: @MrCode Thankyou very much. That is helpful. Reg. Security, see this from the developer's site:                                       **Login:**

The script determines whether username or email is entered and it checks for existing account. When the user enters his password, the script converts the password to md5 string and then compares this to the md5 of the password stored in the database. We never want to know or store the real password of users. That is why we are using md5.

Once logged in we are registering a session and a Cookie with remember me feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<?php
$is_login = isset($_COOKIE["is_login"])?$_COOKIE["is_login"]:'0';

if($is_login == 0){
    echo '<li><a href="#">Client Login</a></li>';
}
else{
    echo '<li><a href="#">Client Tools</a></li>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).
If you want to manage the cookie client-side you can use javascript, I would recomend [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)
I can see already a few responses for server-side.

About using a cookie to detect a user to login, you should read [this article](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through PHP this way:

```
<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['loggedin']) && $_COOKIE['loggedin'] == "yes"): ?>
<li><a href="#">Client Tools</a></li>
<?php else: ?>
<li><a href="#">Client Login</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

At login, you need to create a cookie named "loggedin" with value "yes".

Answer (score 0):

if i am getting ur question right then you will do like this, you need php `$_COKKEIE` to check it

```
if(isset($_COOKIE)){
//your logic
}
```